# What is a 'clutch' in competitive gaming? (Not in the car sense)

Tags: terminology, competitive-gaming

I have heard this term being used to describe a particular Pokemon in a person's team. It comes out of the competitive scene, although I don't really get what it means.

For example, a blog post about [Flygon](https://www.smogon.com/smog/issue11/featured_pokemon) on Smogon which describes it like so:

> Flygon is a staple on many teams as a scout, revenge killer, and all-around reliable clutch Pokémon.

I don't think the term is necessarily restricted to Pokemon as I can recall hearing it in other games such as Counterstrike and Call of Duty.

What does it mean?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The term "clutch" was originally used in sports commentary, describing a player that can keep their head cool and perform well during a tense moment in a game, where the outcome of the competition was at stake.

Definitions of "[clutch](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/clutch)" (adjective):

> 1. happening during a very important or critical time especially in a sports competition
> 2. able to perform well in a very important or critical situation especially in a sports competition

This term has since migrated to competitive gaming, where is used in similar situations, usually in professional gaming events where there is a lot at stake.

A good example of the term is used in a recent [IGN article](http://au.ign.com/articles/2014/07/10/the-international-a-history-of-dota-2as-10-million-tournament) on the [International Dota 2 Championships](http://www.dota2.com/international/announcement):

> Alliance and Na'Vi. Competitive Dota 2 fans dreams came true when the grand finals came down to an incredibly *clutch* play in the last match of the best of five series.

Comment: So is it a specific *turning point* in a match that classifies it as a 'clutch play'? or is it the exact moment/action that *caused* the win? So to take CoD as an example (I don't know MoBAs that well) if someone got the Match Winning Kill, is that a 'clutch kill'? or would it be say, 10 minutes earlier when someone from Team A took out Team B's sniper who was dominating the game up to that point, and Team B couldn't recover?

Comment: @Robotnik "clutch" play is not limited to a turning point in the game, but it can be in some situations. A match winning kill is only really a clutch kill if it determined the winner of the match. A clutch kill occurs when the teams are tied, or very close in points, and a single kill or killstreak in the last seconds of the game win it for the team. As for the sniper example, that isn't really a clutch kill, because it didn't happen in a clutch situation, for example near the end of the match.

Comment: Ok, so there's an emphasis on the match being close at the end rather than just a particular turning point. That makes sense. So when they say Flygon is a good 'clutch Pokemon' it just means it's a good Pokemon to have around near the end of a close battle, as it  is *"able to perform well in a very important or critical situation"*, to use your quote :)

Comment: You are exactly right!

Comment: It doesnt necessarily have to be close when the clutch starts. It can be 5v1, where the 1 annihilates the remaining 5. That is also considered clutch. Clutch can also refer to prevailing against the odds.

Comment: It doesn't have to be on such a macro scale of winning the game. In lane, if I land my thresh hook, and we get first blood because of it, I call it a clutch hook.

Comment: @eyeofthehawks It is more how much pressure there is at the time than how close to the game you are. That being said, usually the most pressure on the teams is near the end of a game. But as you said, 5v1 would also be clutch play because the team of 1 is under so much pressure.

Comment: I'd say that to be described as _clutch_, you need two conditions. 1) a stalemate - common in dota, and 2) a moment in which you cannot go back to the stalemate. It is a do or die scenario.

Comment: An excellent answer. Rather than write my own competing answer, here is a link to more information about the 'clutch' phenomenon in sports: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clutch_(sports)

Answer (score 6):

In FPS games such as Counter-Strike or Call of Duty, I've always heard the term used with a slightly different meaning.

If everyone on your team dies and you are now alone against multiple enemies, and you win the round, we'd say it "was a clutch" or you "clutched".

In this context, it means you won the round against all odds.  It doesn't necessarily mean the round was critical or game-changing.

Answer (score 4):

It means how well you perform under pressure, for example in the crucial moment of the game when it is decided who wins and looses. So Flygon would be a good Pokémon to have in such situations.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of describing what 'clutch' is in words, which others have already covered, ill provide an example of what 'clutch' is since, visual examples are always helpful when trying to understand something.

You don't really have to know too much about the game being played, to know that what Daigo (Ken) does in the video clip is 'clutch'. Just listen to the reaction from the crowd! Heres is a short clip of the clutch play:

Its at a Street Fighter tournament, and its largely considered to be one of the most 'clutch' professional gaming moments of all time: http://kotaku.com/5820907/the-10-best-moments-in-pro-gaming-history (It's ranked #1 on that list).

Ya its that clutch, you will get goosebumps.

Comment: For people that don't know about fighting games(or 3rd strike) there are 3 ways you can stop the damage from an attack, hold the opposite direction to the attacker(some attacks will still deal a small amount), dash back, time a press of towards the attack at a precise moment it would hit to parry it. 

In this situation ken(in white) will die to either of the first two due to the attack which the attacker has to do nothing for as it is a pre-made combo that costs a resource. Ken parries all 15 hits then sets up his own combo into his version of the attack he parried

Answer (score 1):

In Call of Duty a clutch is where you are last alive in say a game mode such as search and destroy vs multiple opponents lets say 4. So its a 4 v 1(You being the one), if you win the round that is known as a 4 v 1 clutch because you killed all enemy's.

Answer (score -1):

Clutch means to come through in a difficult situation. For example, you have 1 hp left, and face two enemies for the win, and eliminate them both.

Contrast with "Choke," where you are in a situation that you probably should win, but fail. For example, you have full health/shield, and face an opponent with 1hp... and you get eliminated.